# Eloquent relations with laravel 4

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, relational-database

I'm always looking for best practice to code now i'm exploring laravel 4 and started code but i'm confused with relations in Eloquent i understand how to implement it but should i add also tables relations for mysql or handling relations from code is good enough ?

Just Tell me what you think about handling relations from mysql by foreign keys and from Eloquent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you will still need to create tables for your data. Whether you want to use database level foreign key constraints is up to you... Laravel doesn't care about that.